# Ruby: Having correct DevKit and Ruby version - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems, installation, devkit

I installed 1.9.3 ruby from http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p448.exe to C:\Ruby193.

I downloaded https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe to C:\ruby_dev_kit and from there ran ruby dk.rb init then ruby dk.rb install

It all installed successfully.

Then when I ran gem install json I keep getting 
    Installing json (1.4.6) The system cannot find the path specified.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ruby/re.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.4.
6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.4.6/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.4.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I also tried gem install json --platform=ruby
Doesn't change anything. It seems that there's c compiler issues but I path defined correctly and DevKit associated as well. 
Tried uninstall and install, doesn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am also getting same issue in window 7 32 bit.